# Custom sorting with DT in Shiny and Rmarkdown using factors

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I have a shiny app where I use the package DT to create interactive tables. For some of the tables, the first column is text where I need custom sorting. Defining the text column as a factor works great to achieve custom sorting within the app. But if I hand over the same data frame to a rmarkdown file, custom sorting does not work anymore (inside the rmarkdown file, the DT table is recreated and the file is finally exported as .html using a download button).

Does anyone know a way to again compel custom sorting based on the factor in rmarkdown / the exported html file? 
I have created an example app below to illustrate the problem.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Example App"),
  
  # Define sidebarLayout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Create download button
      downloadButton(
        outputId = 'download_report',
        label = ' download report',
        icon = icon('download'),
        class = 'form-group shiny-input-container')
    ),
    
    # Show table
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
  
))


# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # set seed
  set.seed(123)
  
  # Define order of categories
  order_cat <- c("Out", "12WO", "ARC")
  
  # Create container
  rv_container <- reactiveValues()
  
  # Create data
  rv_container$df <- tibble(category = c("Out", "ARC", "12WO"),
                            value_1 = sample(1:100, 3),
                            value_2 = sample(1:100, 3),
                            value_3 = sample(1:100, 3),
                            value_4 = sample(1:100, 3)) %>% 
    mutate(select(., starts_with("value")) %>% rowSums(),
           # Switch type of category column to factor
           category = factor(category, 
                             levels = order_cat,
                             labels = order_cat))
  
  # Create output
  output$table <- renderDT({
    
    # Create header of table
    headers <- withTags(
      table(class = "display", 
            thead(tr(th(colspan = 1,"", style = "border-bottom : none;"), 
                     th(colspan = 2, "Header 1", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 2, "Header 2", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "", style = "border-bottom : none;")), 
                  tr(th(colspan = 1, "", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 1", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 2", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 3", style = "text-align: center;"),
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 4", style = "text-align: center;"),
                     th(colspan = 1, "Total", style = "text-align: center;")))))
    
    
    # Create table
    datatable(rv_container$df, 
              container = headers,
              rownames = FALSE, 
              escape = FALSE, 
              options = list(searching = FALSE,
                             paging = FALSE, info = FALSE, autoWidth = FALSE,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-right",
                                                    targets = 1:5)))) %>% 
      formatStyle(c(2, 4, 6), `border-left` = "1px solid #ddd") %>% 
      formatStyle(6, backgroundColor = "lightgrey")
    
  })
  
  # Create html report
  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    
    # Define name
    filename = function(){
      "report.html"
    },
    
    # Define content
    content = function(file) {
      progress_down <- Progress$new(session, min = 1, max = 50)
      on.exit(progress_down$close())
      progress_down$set(message = "Download in progress", value = 5)
      params_markdown <- reactiveValuesToList(rv_container)
      
      progress_down$set(value = 50)
      
      # Create html report
      rmarkdown::render("html_markdown.Rmd",
                        output_file = file,
                        params = params_markdown,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
    
  )
  
})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**html_markdown.Rmd**

````
---
title: "html report created from app"
output: html_document
params:
  df: NA
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)```

```{r cars, echo = FALSE}

    # Create header
    headers <- withTags(
      table(class = "display", 
            thead(tr(th(colspan = 1,"", style = "border-bottom : none;"), 
                     th(colspan = 2, "Header 1", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 2, "Header 2", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "", style = "border-bottom : none;")), 
                  tr(th(colspan = 1, "", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 1", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 2", style = "text-align: center;"), 
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 3", style = "text-align: center;"),
                     th(colspan = 1, "Value 4", style = "text-align: center;"),
                     th(colspan = 1, "Total", style = "text-align: center;")))))
    
    
    dt <- datatable(df, container = headers,
                                 rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, 
                                 options = list(searching = FALSE,
                                                paging = FALSE, info = FALSE, autoWidth = FALSE,
                                                columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-right",
                                                                       targets = 1:5)))) %>% 
      formatStyle(c(2, 4, 6), `border-left` = "1px solid #ddd") %>% 
      formatStyle(6, backgroundColor = "lightgrey")
    
    dt```
````

Supplement: I'm using the newest version of R, DT, shiny and rmarkdown. I also know that there are some workarounds to bypass the problem like creating another numerical column that is used for sorting but invisible. I'd like to avoid these workarounds and find a solution based on the factors instead because otherwise I'd need to manually adapt many different tables.